# Tox and lib and lib64 and site-packages

Tags: python, testing, coverage.py, tox

I'm using `tox` and `coverage.py` to run tests of my Python project in my continuous build server.  I also have a package `pkg_x` from a vendor (not available on PyPI) that I've installed using `python3.5 setup.py install`, which puts it in `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.  Now I need to make that package available to the testing code.

My current `tox.ini` looks like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py35

[testenv]
deps = nose
       coverage
commands = coverage run -m nose []
sitepackages = True
```

and I run the tests like so:

```
python3.5 -m tox -- --verbose --with-doctest
```

That fails spectacularly - none of the dependency packages listed in my local `setup.py` (e.g. public stuff like `more_itertools`) can be found, even though it does create directories like `.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/more_itertools` that seem to contain the relevant packages.  If I fire up `.tox/py35/bin/python3.5`, `sys.path` looks like this:

```
>>> [re.compile('.*\\.tox').sub('.tox', x) for x in sys.path]
['',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python35.zip',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5', 
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

If I remove the `sitepackages = True` line from my `tox.ini`, then I do get farther, in that packages like `more_itertools` and the rest of the stuff in my `setup.py` dependencies can now be found, but the vendor package `pkg_x` I mentioned above still can't be found.  And `sys.path` looks like this:

```
>>> [re.compile('.*\\.tox').sub('.tox', x) for x in sys.path]
['',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python35.zip',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5', 
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '.tox/py35/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

In neither case does `.tox/py35/` seem to contain the vendor package `pkg_x` anywhere.  And although the directory `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` is listed when I fire up `.tox/py35/bin/python3.5` manually, `pkg_x` isn't actually found when running the tests.

It also looks like `sitepackages = True` has the opposite effect from what it's documented to do at 
http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-sitepackages=True|False , right?

Advice very appreciated!

Comment: I put a comment on a Tox issue that looks like the same thing I'm seeing: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/461#issuecomment-303855697

Comment: `tox` creates it's own virtualenv's. How familiar are you with virtualenv?  Activate the venv in the `.tox` directory and debug from there.

Answer (score 5):

`Tox` creates a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), then runs it's tests from inside that environment.

The `--sitepackages` argument is a switch determining whether the virtualenv gets access to globally installed packages.

The 'normal' way to run tox would be to simply say `tox`; installing it via pip or via an OS package should put it into your path. ie:

```
$ tox
```

Which is the same as saying:

```
$ tox -c tox.ini
```

Where you invoke tox directly, `python -m tox`, it may do something, but this is a red flag to me.  This command seems unlikely to activate the relevant virtual environment, which would explain your package availability woes.  It fits because when you omit `sitepackages`, it actually adds the global packages because it thinks it is inside a virtualenv and so adds, what it thinks are the `local` sitepackages, although they're actually global.  The reverse happens when you make it true because when it goes looking for global packages it can't find them. Whatever, because you're not invoking tox as expected it's as confused as we are.

So just use the `tox` command provided.

But wait there's more:  You say you have a package which is required, but not available on pypi.  So how is tox going to install it?  The tox docs suggest a couple of ways (use a requirements.txt), but the most direct to describe here is to activate the env and install it manually.

Also good if you need to debug further: step into the `.tox` directory and activate the venv manually. eg:

```
$ source .tox/testenv/bin/activate
```

(where `testenv` is the name you used between brackets in the `tox.ini`).

Now install the package however you did it before eg: `pip install pkg_x`

Deactivate the venv when you're done with it this way:

```
$ deactivate
```

Try `tox` now?

If we're on the right track [learn more about virtualenv here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/)

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure you're absolutely right that my understanding needs work.  However, the suggested solution of pre-installing into the virtual environment won't work, because this is in a continuous build server, where the working environment is rebuilt with every run.  I'd have to install it every time a test is run, and the installation needs human interaction.

Comment: The reason I'm using `python3 -m tox` instead of simply `tox` is so that I can control which version of python is used to invoke Tox, rather than depending on the shebang line in the `tox` script.  I thought this was a supported use case?

Comment: For the dependancy use tox's `DEPS=`.  For the versions, that's the key sales pitch of tox... it tests multiple versions of python simultaneously. You can configure each environment in the tox then it will build and test on each.  [Check the manual ;-)](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the solution to my problem is to change the `commands` line in my `tox.ini` from this:

```
commands = coverage run -m nose []
```

to this:

```
commands = python -m coverage run -m nose []
```

The effect is that `python` is now a virtualenv-mapped command, which loads the correct Python interpreter, loads the `coverage` module, and runs it.  Without `python -m`, it just finds whatever `coverage` executable is in my `PATH` and runs it, with unpredictable results.  `whitelist_externals` could be used, but it would only band-aid the problem.

Then if I *also* add the `sitepackages = True` line, it successfully sees the `pkg_x` I installed from the vendor, and my tests succeed.

Comment: @john-mee's answer above showed me the necessary investigation tools - namely loading the virtualenv in the `.tox` directory to see what it sees.

Comment: Another variation might be `nosetests --with-coverage ...`